# The extract total distinct count for two columns from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In the table PRODUCT, contains the attribute:

`P_CODE, P_DESCRIPT, P_INDATE, P_QOH, P_MIN, P_PRICE, P_DISCOUNT, V_CODE`

I am trying to find how to display the total distinct count of P_code for each V_code type in the product table.

I have written this but it shows as a error, can't quite figure out why.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT P_CODE,V_CODE 
  FROM PRODUCT
)
```

Much appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count distinct` with a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   V_code, COUNT (DISTINCT P_code)
FROM     product
GROUP BY V_code
```